# Проблема на VDS с запуском Nginx

Tags: nginx, vds, ubuntu, ssl

Есть VDS сервер Hetzner, на нем Ubuntu доступ к которому только через SSH. На нем обновили ключ ssl для nginx, но распаковать «забыли». Потом сервак перезагрузили...

Теперь к серваку не получается подключится, он скорее всего стопорится на запуске nginx(который требует ввести пароль для ключа).

Возможно ли решить данную проблему и получить доступ без переустановки сервера(есть важные данные на которых нет бекапа)?

Тех поддержка Hetzner рекомендует поискать решение проблемы в инете?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обычно к VDS всегда есть доступ по VNC консоли, уточните у вашего хостера. Если есть тогда сможете подключится к серверу даже когда он не доступен по сети.

Comment: VNC как услуга есть, но пакет программ не установлен. Поэтому этот метод тоже отподает.

Comment: На самом vds севере ничего не должно быть установлено, подключение по vnc должно происходить через хост сервер на котором запущен vds, это позволяет даже переустанавливать вручную ос на vds.

Comment: В области внс - предлагает поставить программу на сервак. Но с проблемой разобрался, у Hetzner есть система "спасения", которая запускает мини образ linux с примонтированным моим образом.